# How to read multiple txt file from a single folder in Python?

Tags: python, file

How can I read multiple txt file from a single folder in Python?

I tried with the following code but it is not working.

```
import glob

import errno

path = '/home/student/Desktop/thesis/ndtvnews/garbage'

files = glob.glob(path)

for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            print name

        for line in f:
            print line,

        f.close()

    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your glob isn't correct. You should add a `/*` to the end of your path to select all files (or directories) in your path, and then check if they are files with `os.path.isfile`. Something like:

```
from os.path import isfile
files=filter(isfile,glob.glob('%s/*'%path))
```

You also have an issue with the actual opening. When your `with` statement ends, the file is closed and `f` is no longer accessible. Anything you do with the file should be under the `with` statement. And you shouldn't explicitly close it.

Comment: you can try:

import os
import pandas as pd

data_set = pd.DataFrame()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("<your source folder>"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            df = pd.read_csv(root + "/" + file, header=None)
            data_set = pd.concat([data_set, df])
data_set.to_csv("<your destination folder>/tx.txt", index=False, header=False)

Comment: @Loku Did you make this comment on the wrong post? It doesn't seem to be related.