# Read multiple files in python and combine filenames and content into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops

I have the following lists in python created by reading files

```py
files_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

The contents of the files are character vectors as follows

```py
A = ["A1"]
B = ["A2", "B1"]
C = ["A3", "B3", "C3", "C3"]
D = []
```

I would like to create the following dataframe

```
Col1   Col2
A      A1
B      A2, B1
C      A3, B3, C3
D
```

The filenames should be rendered as one column and the second column should contain the content of the files as a single line.

I tried the following code using a for loop. Note that this is a toy dataset and my dataset is a bit larger

```py
import pandas as pd


df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in list_name:
    for j in i:
        df3["Col1"] = j
        df3["Col2"] = i
```

How do i accomplish the same using the for loop
I request someone to take a look. The df3 object i generated was empty

Comment: Can you look into this and see if this addresses your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat)

Comment: You can also look into this for [reading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224610/how-to-read-multiple-txt-file-from-a-single-folder-in-python) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111243/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-in-a-folder-with-python) and please make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


files_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
files_cont = [
    ["A1"],
    ["A2", "B1"],
    ["A3", "B3", "C3", "C3"],
    [],
]

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"contents": list(map(sorted, map(set, files_cont)))}, index=files_list)
print(df3)
```

```
       contents
A          [A1]
B      [A2, B1]
C  [A3, B3, C3]
D            []
```

We create a new `pd.DataFrame` using a dict so that the key is used for the column name (I used `"contents"` but choose whatever you feel like) and providing the `index` keyword argument to specify the rows.

As the question removed duplicates in the list, each content list is passed first to the `set` function to eliminate duplicated elements, then to the `sorted` function to get back a list with sorted elements. If you dont need that just use `{"contents": files_cont}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your files are CSVs you can do the following to use the for loop:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
directory = "C:/your/path/to/all/files/*.csv"
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col", "contents"])

for file in glob.glob(directory):
        col = file.split(sep="\\")[1].split(".")[0]
        try:
            temp = pd.read_csv(file, header=None).values.flatten()
            df3 = df3.append({"col": col, "contents": temp}, ignore_index=True)
        except:
            df3 = df3.append({"col": col, "contents": None}, ignore_index=True)
```

you get the following DataFrame:

```
    col contents
0   A   [A1]
1   B   [A2, B1]
2   C   [A3, B3, C3]
3   D   None
```